# Running unit test in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am running unit test for angular app.I expect ng init to be called

Component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.topToolBarService.change.subscribe(customer => {
      this.filter.customerid = customer;
      this.customerid = customer;
      this.getData();
    });
```

service.ts

```
@Output() change: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

sendCustomer(customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.change.emit(customer);
}
```

Actual test:

```
it('should call ngonint',()=>{
    mockService.createSpyObj();
    mockService.change = of("0LPT_id0306");
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.ngOnInit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

> expected: test passed ; Actual:TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSpyObj' of undefined

Comment: Did you read through the [angular testing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing)? Do that first and if you are still stuck come back and update your question with a full [mcve]. What you have now is not enough to determine what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the error:
`Actual:TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSpyObj' of undefined` says that this method or property is undefined. Did you forget to mock it?